# PHP imap_search multiple FROM

Tags: php, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I'm trying to use multiple FROM filter in imap_search but seems it doesn't work. I might be doing in wrong way. Please draw my attention.

Code :

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'FROM "John" FROM "Katrihan"');
```

This code doesn't work. Please tell me the alternative.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

An IMAP search expression has an implied AND prefix operator.  If you are looking for messages from either "John" or "Katrihan" then the expression should be 'OR FROM "John" FROM "Katrihan"'.

Comment: No sir. I want emails with both names.